# Getting error after Angular cli update

Tags: angular-cli

My **angular-cli** version was **beta.16**

I try to update by following command

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

after succesfully install when i try to run any ng command

```
ng version 
ng help
```

I am getting this error

```
ng help
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config/config.js:15
    constructor(_configPath, schema, configJson, fallbacks = []) {
                                                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need Node version 6.x or higher

take a look here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4604

Comment: Yeah, that was it for me - my CI server was pulling in a Node 5:10:0 docker image... switching to 7.5.0 fixed it

Comment: Argh, so the documentation at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cli-quickstart.html incorrectly states that 4.x.x is good enough. Wonderful.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you need Node version 6.x or higher.

Quick solution posted on [Github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4809) by *cdvillagra*:

```
npm cache clean -f
npm install -g n
n stable
```

(you might need to prefix those commands with `sudo`).

Also, on Ubuntu or similar you may want to remove your old version of node and then link the new one:

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node`